# Preposition before the word "agreement"

Tags: prepositions

> I have done the work **on** his agreement.

This sounds good to me, but I am not sure. Online dictionaries didn't helped me much.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to say this is as you said:

> I have done work on his agreement.

You could also say:

> I have done work with his agreement.

This isn't wrong, but it is also not as commonly said.  The meaning changes subtly.  It makes you think of the agreement as some sort of shared project of which others participate.  When in doubt, you should use "on" rather than "with" here.

> I have done work for his agreement.

This too isn't wrong, but it is slightly less idiomatic.  Again the meaning changes subtly.  You're saying you dedicated time towards his agreement.  So the emphasis here is that you've dedicated time/effort, whereas with "on", it is more matter-of-fact.  And again, when in doubt, you should use "on" here.

On the other hand, you would *not* use "in", because it isn't a place or container of some sort.  If you have any questions on any other prepositions, please let me know in the comments and I'll try to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Using "**On**" proposition is correct in your example because before that "*Verb*" used and action and something happened.

The prepositions we can use with "agreement" according to the *Oxford Collocations Dictionary*:

- List item

**in an/the** agreement  e.g *a clause **in** the agreement*

**under an/the** agreement e.g ***Under*** the agreement, the farmer is not allowed to use this field.

agreement **between** e.g *an agreement **between** the company and the unions*

agreement **on** e.g *They signed two agreements **on** improving economic cooperation.*

agreement **with** e.g a *trade agreement **with** China*

**by** e.g *The separation is **by** mutual agreement*.

**In** e.g *I think we are all **in** agreement that prices should be kept low*.

In agreement **with** e.g, *I am in agreement **with** you that she should be given more responsibilities.*

**With** agreement e.g, ***With*** the agreement of all members of the club, we decided to organize a trip.

agreement **among** e.g, *There is agreement **among** teachers that changes need to be made.*

agreement **between** e.g, *As yet there is no agreement **between** the two sides.*

agreement **on** e.g, *As yet there is no agreement **on** policies.*